# BEGIN blocks in Perl

Tags: perl

Searching the Internet, I get that the BEGIN block will get evaluated and executed in the compile phase. But can the @INC or other variables be inherited?

Below is what I wrote for testing. The directory structure is as:

```
|-- alexpackages
|   |-- alex1.pm
|   `-- alex2.pm
|-- foo.pl
`-- main.pl
```

For each file:

cat alexpackages/alex1.pm

```perl
package alex1;

sub foo()
{
    print "this is alex1::foo\n";
}

1;
```

cat alexpackages/alex2.pm

```perl
package alex2;

sub foo2()
{
    print "this is is alex2::foo2\n";
}

1;
```

cat foo.pl

```perl
alex1::foo();
```

cat main.pl

```perl
BEGIN
{
    push(@INC, '~/programs/perl/alexpackages');
}

use strict;
use warnings;

use alex1;
use alex2;

#alex1::foo();           # 1. This works good
system("perl foo.pl");   # 2. This fails
```

Just as what my program tells that the @INC does not work for a new system call. It seems to me that system call will not inherit the system environment. Am I right?

And can how I make the environment variables to the following system call?

Comment: You can use the [`lib` package](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) to add things to `@INC`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processes started with `system` *will* inherit the environment variables from the calling process, but `@INC` is just a global Perl variable, not a system environment variable. It is not visible outside the Perl program.

A couple of notes on your code

- Package names, being globals, should be capitalised, so your packages should be `Alex1` and `Alex2`, in files `alexpackages/Alex1.pm` and `alexpackages/Alex2.pm`
- It is best to use the `lib` pragma to manipulate `@INC`, so

  ```
  use lib '~/programs/perl/alexpackages'
  ```

  is best. And a `use` statement creates an implicit `BEGIN` block, so that is also unnecessary.
- It is wrong to use prototypes on Perl subroutines, so `sub foo()` should be just `sub foo`
- You may prefer to use [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) to copy the symbols of a package into the calling code. That way you don't have to fully-qualify your subroutine name when you call it, like `foo()` instead of `Alex1::foo()`

The code would look like this

**main.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '~/programs/perl/alexpackages';

use Alex1;

foo();
```

**~/programs/perl/alexpackages/Alex1.pm**

```
package Alex1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT = qw/ foo /;

sub foo {
  print "This is Alex1::foo\n";
}

1;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to specify library search directories both from within a Perl script or the command line. Here are two things you could do to make another directory available to the Perl script you invoke with `system`:

```
$ENV{PERL5LIB} = "~/programs/perl/alexpackages";
system("perl foo.pl");


system("perl -I~/programs/perl/alexpackages foo.pl");
```

Both `PERL5LIB` and the `-I` switch are documented in [`perlrun`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlrun).

Comment: +1 I see that my post answered the specific question asked, but didn't offer a solution to passing on a copy of `@INC`